# cache dependency on file asp.net - not firing the event

Tags: asp.net, file, caching, dependencies

I configured cache dependency on a file on the server, the cache dependency event stops responding to file changes once in 2 or 3 days. After I perform IISReset on the server, it works fine.
How to debug this type of issues? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your application can respond to cache dependency event only if it's in the running state. Web sites are created so that they recycle themselves after some value of inactivity. After that time, your application is simply not working until new request comes along. During that time it cannot catch cache dependency events because it's simply not running. I believe that this is your main problem.